# How to use the body's scrollbar for a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If a user types more text than the textarea's area then the textrea gets a scrollbar.

Is there a way to just have the texarea extend so it uses the body's scrollbars?

Is this possible with css? jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible with jQuery or plain JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/UDTQ5/2/

```
function resize(){
    var ta = $('#ta').get(0);
    ta.style.height = (ta.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

Or:

```
function resize(){
    var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
    ta.style.height = (ta.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like chrome doesn't the padding in scrollHeight... This fix works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UDTQ5/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [textarea AutoGrow plugin (Demo/Download)](http://figovo.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/cXQVu/

```
$("textarea").on('keyup', function() {
    var rows=$("textarea").val().split('\n').length;
    $(this).css('height', rows*20+'px');
});
```